# Enhance regex to validate phone number

Tags: java, regex

I have created a regex for validating a telephone number with following requirement:

- Allowed chars: `+ space ( ) – 0-9`
- `+` or `(` can be first char after trim like `(+61) 312 405 678` or `+61 312 405 678`.
- Dash is allowed anywhere in the number.
- Length min 8 max 16 – show error in case of boundary conditions

But I need to enhance it a bit. I want to validate that if `+` is in the number it must be only in the beginning but my regex is not checking this. Please help. This is my regex so far:

```
^[\\(?\\+?(\\d{2})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{0,})[- ]?(\\d{0,})[- ]?(\\d{0,})]{9,16}$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @brian-roach: i checked all the regex supplied their they all have the same issue i just mentioned about open and close bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Adding \+{0,1} to the beginning should do the trick.

The finished regex would look like this

`^\+{0,1}[\(?\+?(\d{2})\)?[ -]?(\d{0,})[- ]?(\d{0,})[- ]?(\d{0,})]{9,16}$`

Comment: That's close, but the `+` can be inside the first `()` or outside. I just noticed his whole regex is a group, which I don't think is what he needs.

Comment: @brian-roach : yes that's what i need enhancement to what i have already created !!

Comment: also i just checked with some more test cases and the above regex failed : +61) 456 789 980

it should have stated false for the above input as we dont have an open bracket but it is giving  true for the same !

Comment: Found solution, thought it might help someone else in future: 

^[[\\+?[\\d]{2}]?[\\s \\-]?[\\d [\\- \\s]?]]{9,15}$|[\({1}]\\+{1}\\d{2}[\){1}][[\\s \\-]?[\\d [\\- \\s]?]]{9,10}$ 

Did this myself atlast ;)

Comment: Doesn't Java support `\+?` instead of `\+{0,1}`?

Answer (score 0):

I would throw out all the optional characters, then check if it matches `\\+?\\d{8,16}`.

Alternatively, allow for arbitrary amounts of punctuation anywhere; `[\\s().-]*(\\+[\\s().-]*)?(\\d[\\s().-]*){8,16}`.

Comment: Found solution, thought it might help someone else in future:

^[[\\+?[\\d]{2}]?[\\s \\-]?[\\d [\\- \\s]?]]{9,15}$|[\\({1}]\\+{1}\\d{2}[\\){1}][[\\s \\-]?[\\d [\\- \\s]?]]{9,10}$

Did this myself atlast ;)

Comment: Your regex looks mighty strange, and will fail if there are multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: could u suggest any improvement ??

Comment: Reluctantly edited my response. It would help if we knew in what context and for what purpose you need this.